# Do geometry theorems of n dimension hold true for all topological spaces of n dimension?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Do geometry theorems of n dimension hold true for all topological spaces of n dimension? Let's say that there's a geometric theorem proven for a euclidean space of dimension 2, does that same theorem hold true for all topological spaces or not?

Answer (score 2):

Not. Definitely not. For instance, it's true in dimension 2 euclidean space that any loop can be continuously contracted to a point; but on the surface of the torus, this is definitely *not* true.

You might say "But that's not really *geometric*", and you're right. So let's try another: if you take a straight line in euclidean space, there's another straight line parallel to it (i.e., that does not intersect it). Now look at the unit sphere in 3-space, a 2-dimensional manifold. The analog to "straight line" is "great circle". But any two great circles on the sphere intersect.